# is there a way to get output in select query with substring between a special characters in the output column

Tags: sql

I am using select query and output 2 columns from a table. one column contains data in strings delimited by special characters ":" . I need to output the data from the columns with string output between the first instance of the special character and second instance of the special character

table - `ACC_TABLE`
command used :

```
select SC_NAME, SUBSTR(PROP,1,30)
from ACC_TABLE where PROP like '%REC%' and like PROP like '%NEC%'
```

output of first 2 line--

```
SC_NAME  PROP

00000   {"sender":"","message":"@{source.message

1000NN  {"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo

2040NN  {"sender":"NEC@notify.com","message":"Dear Custo
```

I require to get distinct and unique sender i.e between first"sender":" and "," from the column name PROP, also these values are not specific length so I am not able to use standard substr with fixed width.

```
select SC_NAME, SUBSTR(PROP,1,30)
from ACC_TABLE where PROP like '%REC%' and like PROP like '%NEC%'
```

expected to get 
distinct and unique sender i.e between first"sender":" and "," from the column name PROP, also these values are not specific length so I am not able to use standard substr with fixed width.

Comment: You should check which escape characters for the RDMS that you are using

Comment: First we need to know the DBMS and it's version that you're using, as the solutions may heavily depend on that. And second, this looks like it could be some JSON? If yes that could make things a lot easier on certain DBMS. Is it JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below logic to get only the sender name/id.

Just add another column and use this logic to get convert the actual column and use distinct to get unique senders

select
reverse(
substring(
reverse(substring(replace(substring('{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo',1,patindex('%message%','{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo')-1),'sender',''),
patindex('%[A-Za-Z0-9]%',replace(substring('{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo',1,patindex('%message%','{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo')-1),'sender','')),
len(replace(substring('{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo',1,patindex('%message%','{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo')-1),'sender','')))),
patindex('%[A-Za-Z0-9]%',
reverse(substring(replace(substring('{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo',1,patindex('%message%','{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo')-1),'sender',''),
patindex('%[A-Za-Z0-9]%',replace(substring('{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo',1,patindex('%message%','{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo')-1),'sender','')),
len(replace(substring('{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo',1,patindex('%message%','{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo')-1),'sender',''))))),
len(reverse(substring(replace(substring('{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo',1,patindex('%message%','{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo')-1),'sender',''),
patindex('%[A-Za-Z0-9]%',replace(substring('{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo',1,patindex('%message%','{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo')-1),'sender','')),
len(replace(substring('{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo',1,patindex('%message%','{"sender":"REC","message":"Dear Custo')-1),'sender',''))))))
)